# Custom field group weight order on contact summary page?

Tags: custom-fields

As far as i can tell, the weight of custom field groups is not respected in the order they are displayed on the contact summary page - is that accurate?

I can't find anything obvious that controls that order - if anyone knows otherwise i would appreciate it!

Civi v 4.7.27 and drupal 7

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The 'order' only controls a field set in respect of other Custom Field sets, it does not relate to Core field sets that show on Summary.

Eg on demo I just made a new field set for Contact. It showed to the right of Constituent Information.

I then edited the order to push my new set to the 'top' and it then showed on the left which Constituent Information then showed on the right.

Comment: huh, you're right - sorry. 
It's not doing it on my (updated from an old version fwiw) site - i should look into whether any template stuff is being overwritten perhaps.